# Using subprocess to access GEE fails to connect, shows "Google Earth Engine API has not been used in project 522309567947"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

So im trying to run earthengine command using subprocess in python using colab,

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = 'MY-PROJECT'
command = f"gcloud config get-value project; earthengine ls"
with open('out.txt','w+') as fout:
    with open('err.txt','w+') as ferr:
        ret = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True, env=my_env)
        print(ret.stdout.decode())
```

the output for `gcloud config get-value project` is correct with 'MY-PROJECT', but when command for `earthengine ls` it somehow runs in project 522309567947

this problem occurs before in here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4228
but it only solves when ee.Initialize() in colab, not when using subprocess to run earthengine command

i try to set my environment

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = 'MY-PROJECT'
```

and checking the subprocess command in the same line about the config of gcp projects we're on
`command = f"gcloud config get-value project; earthengine ls`

the get-value command returns correct value, but when running earthengine command it returns in different project.

i expect earthengine command to run in the same gcp project